# LED board in Python using Tkinter, matrix and pixels

Tags: python, tkinter

As a part of a Python project I am trying to make an LED board using **Tkinter** library. This board should receive an input (a sentence) and show it on the board. I have started by making `7*6` matrices of zeros and ones for each letter but I really don't know what to do next and how should these letters be shown on the board.

For example:

```
A = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Letters should be shown as below:
[image]

Comment: I would suggest having a dictionary mapping a letter the the pattern `letters = { 'a' : [ [ 0,1,1,1,0,0],...]` and use a canvas to plot them with either `create_rectangle` or `create_oval` up to preference.

Comment: Thank you for answering.Can you explain a little more about plotting

Comment: Iterating through your given string and then drawing on the canvas to represent those letters.

Comment: Excuse me for taking your time but can you give me an example for one of the letters. how to draw it on my canvas I am really stuck

Answer (score 0):

Example code

```
import tkinter as tk

# Should have constants in another .py or .json file 
DOT_WIDTH = 20
DOT_HEIGHT = 20

LETTER_WIDTH = 6 * DOT_WIDTH
LETTER_HEIGHT = 7 * DOT_HEIGHT

LETTERS = { 'A' :
                (
                    (0,1,1,1,0,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,1,1,1,1,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0)
                ),
            'B' :
                (
                    (1,1,1,1,0,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,1,1,1,0,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,0,0,0,1,0),
                    (1,1,1,1,1,0)
                )
            }

class LED(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, width = 500, height = 300, bg = 'black')

        self._cursor_pos = 2
        self._line_pos = 2

    def draw_letter(self, char):
        for i, row in enumerate(LETTERS.get(char, ())):
            for j, col in enumerate(row):
                if col:
                    self.create_oval( self._cursor_pos + j * DOT_WIDTH,
                                      self._line_pos + i * DOT_HEIGHT,
                                      self._cursor_pos + (j + 1) * DOT_WIDTH,
                                      self._line_pos + (i + 1) * DOT_HEIGHT,
                                      fill = 'red'
                                    )

        self._cursor_pos += LETTER_WIDTH

    def new_line(self, size):
        if self._cursor_pos + size >= self.winfo_width():
            self._cursor_pos = 2
            self._line_pos += LETTER_HEIGHT

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._led = LED(master)
        self._led.pack(expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

        entry = tk.Entry(master)
        entry.pack(fill = tk.X)
        entry.bind("<Return>", lambda e: self.draw_sentence(entry.get()))

    def draw_sentence(self, s):
        for word in s.split():
            self._led.new_line(len(word) * LETTER_WIDTH)  
            for char in word:
                self._led.draw_letter(char.upper())
            self._led._cursor_pos += LETTER_WIDTH//2 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! your answers were very useful just one problem I don't want the letters to come in multiple lines my next step is to give some animations to this code like moving from left to right therefore all the letters have to be in one line do you have any suggestions for the animations aswell?

Comment: Well this is an example. It's up to you to edit it to fit, II can't provide everything for you. If you want to have animations then I suggest looking towards moving the each item or clearing the whole canvas than then re-drawing it again.

Comment: Thank you very much.Your advice really helped me